# Batch file run cmd1 if time 10pm-4am else run cmd2

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file and within that batch file I need to run one of two commands depending on time of my server.

If the time is between 22:00:00 and 03:30:00 -- xcopy /Y a\1.txt c\1.txt

If the time is before or after this range -- -- xcopy /Y b\1.txt c\1.txt

This will use xcopy to switch a file back and forth depending on the time.

I know this is easy but my brain just won't work atm lol

Edit:

Went with 22:00 and 4:00... this is what I came up with but it doesn't seem like the best way...

```
set current_time=%time:~0,5% 

if "%current_time%" lss "22:00" goto daycycle 

if "%current_time%" gtr " 4:00" goto daycycle 

echo Do this between 10pm and 4am

goto continue 

:daycycle 

echo Do this before 10pm and after 4am

:continue
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "now=%time: =0%"

    set "task=day"
    if "%now%" lss "03:30:00,00" ( set "task=night" ) 
    if "%now%" geq "22:00:00,00" ( set "task=night" )

    call :task_%task%

    endlocal
    exit /b

:task_day
    :: do daily task
    goto :eof

:task_night
    :: do nightly task
    goto :eof
```

EDITED - The previous code should work under the conditions in the original question. But will fail in different time configurations. This should solve the usual problems

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :getTime now

    set "task=day"
    if "%now%" lss "03:30:00,00" ( set "task=night" ) 
    if "%now%" geq "22:00:00,00" ( set "task=night" )

    call :task_%task%

    echo %now%

    endlocal
    exit /b

:task_day
    :: do daily task
    goto :eof

:task_night
    :: do nightly task
    goto :eof

:: getTime
::    This routine returns the current (or passed as argument) time
::    in the form hh:mm:ss,cc in 24h format, with two digits in each
::    of the segments, 0 prefixed where needed.
:getTime returnVar [time]
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    :: Retrieve parameters if present. Else take current time
    if "%~2"=="" ( set "t=%time%" ) else ( set "t=%~2" )

    :: Test if time contains "correct" (usual) data. Else try something else
    echo(%t%|findstr /i /r /x /c:"[0-9:,.apm -]*" >nul || ( 
        set "t="
        for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('2^>nul robocopy "|" . /njh') do (
            if not defined t set "t=%%a,00"
        )
        rem If we do not have a valid time string, leave
        if not defined t exit /b
    )

    :: Check if 24h time adjust is needed
    if not "%t:pm=%"=="%t%" (set "p=12" ) else (set "p=0")

    :: Separate the elements of the time string
    for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=:.,-PpAaMm " %%a in ("%t%") do (
        set "h=%%a" & set "m=00%%b" & set "s=00%%c" & set "c=00%%d" 
    )

    :: Adjust the hour part of the time string
    set /a "h=100%h%+%p%"

    :: Clean up and return the new time string
    endlocal & if not "%~1"=="" set "%~1=%h:~-2%:%m:~-2%:%s:~-2%,%c:~-2%" & exit /b
```

Comment: I tried your edited version, but it fail "randomly" depending on certain times. I think there is a problem with the `lss` and `geq` operators, as well as your `set /a` line. I resorted to a more simple version of `set hr=%TIME:~0,2%` and `if "%hr%" == "0" ( goto eof )` (with 23 more lines for each hour)

Comment: @servermanfail, You are right. There were at least to possible problems in the posted code. Now corrected.

Comment: Alternatively if both times are after 12pm:

 `if "%now%" geq "02:00:00,00" ( 
  if "%now%" lss "08:00:00,00" (
   set "task=night" 
  )
 )`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set hour=%time:~0,2%
set min=%time:~3,2%

if %hour% GEQ 22 (
    xcopy /Y a\1.txt c\1.txt
) ELSE (
   if %hour% LEQ 3 (
       if %hour% EQU 3 if %min% GTR 30 (
           xcopy /Y b\1.txt c\1.txt
           goto :END
       )
       xcopy /Y a\1.txt c\1.txt
   ) ELSE (
       xcopy /Y b\1.txt c\1.txt
       goto :END
   )
)

:END
```

And I'm rather sure that will do what you want. Manual `if` statements for the win! Note it would be a lot easier if it was `22:00` to `4:00` or `3:00`. I had to incorperate the `:30` minute checker.

But yea, it might not work, so just check it before you put it up on your server.

Monacraft.

Comment: Well now that I made it you can just CP this and try it out.

Comment: 22:00 and 4:00 is easier and would work just fine.  I just want to make sure one command happens exactly between those times and the other command exactly outside of that time period.

I edited the question with what I came up with but I don't think it's the best way.

Answer (score -1):

What should work:

```
@echo off
:loop
set hour=%time:~0,2%
set min=%time:~3,2%

cls
ECHO %hour%
ECHO %min%
ECHO This %I%

IF %hour% == 14 GOTO Test2
goto loop

:Test2
IF %min% == 58 GOTO YUP
IF %min% == 59 GOTO LATE
Goto loop
:YUP
SET I=0
GOTO loop

:LATE
SET I=NOPE
GOTO loop
```

Comment: It would be great to add some explanation how your code works.